# How to show Arraylist items in horizontal scroll view?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, scrollview

```
           protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        details = new ArrayList<Details>();

        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL(url);

        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                Details detailAll = new Details();

                detailAll.setResType(jsonobject.optString("resType"));
                detailAll.setName(jsonobject.optString("resName"));
                detailAll.setUrl(jsonobject.optString("resLink"));


                details.add(detailAll);


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
```

Till now I am parsing JSON object in the spinner, I want  to show them in Horizontal scroll view.Means strings will be shown in text views, not in spinner

Thanks
     //       TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

```
        MaterialSpinner mySpinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
        mySpinner.setHint("My liked video is ");
        nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Details bean : details) {
            nameList.add(bean.getResType());              
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DetailsActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameList);

        adapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


 }
```

Comment: you can use a recycler with linerlayoutmanager with horizontal scroll

Comment: Do you know any site, links or blogs to show an examples?

Comment: just search on google or stackvoerflow. should give you enough exmaples to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Show Data In this way. Use **ViewPager+PagerAdapter**

More information , Check this Post

[Android Horizontal scrolling image gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429556/android-horizontal-scrolling-image-gallery)

Thanks