# HorizontalScrollView inside a ScrollView android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView inside a VerticalScrollView. If I scroll Horizontally , the scrolling is smooth. But if I scroll Vertically , the scroll is not smooth, it is getting scrolled horizontally sometimes. How to make the vertical scroll smooth ?

Here is my xml ,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sasank.calendarview.MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/chapter_list"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chapter_list"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/calendar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </HorizontalScrollView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Im using a Vertical LinearLayoutManager for Chapter_list Recyclerview and GridLayoutManager for Calendar RecyclerView

Comment: Not sure if it has been fixed yet, but nesting of ScrollView's isn't supported or recommended. I had to build a custom Calendar for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

You can try this, but still problems connected to the nested scrolling and so on are actually common. People have had the same problems here on StackOverflow, take a look, i hope it can help you: [Problems with Nested Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

I have vertical scrollview and horizontal recycleview photo gallery in one of my projects and it works fine. Here's the code:

**fragment/activity layout:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       ...

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        />
            ...

        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**item:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_item_view_image"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="109dp"
    android:layout_height="109dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**adapter:**

```
public class HorizontalPhotosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalPhotosAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView riv;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            riv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_item_view_image);

        }
    }


    public HorizontalPhotosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList, String[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bitmapList = bitmapList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_item_view, parent, false);

        if (itemView.getLayoutParams ().width == RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            itemView.getLayoutParams ().width = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.riv.setImageBitmap(bitmapList.get(position));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bitmapList.size();
    }
}
```

**implementation in fragment/activity:**

```
            horizontalAdapter=new HorizontalPhotosAdapter(getContext(), bitmapList);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
            horizontalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
```