# Android : clickable Image horizontal slider using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, android-constraintlayout, horizontal-scrolling

I want to add horizontal image scroller like an image attached below. I know there are solutions but all solutions are 4 to 5 years old and after Kotlin and constraint layout I am assuming that now there are some good methods to achieve this. Please help me out and share the best and easy way to do this. Thanks in advance.
 [image]

Comment: Have you tried using HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429556/android-horizontal-scrolling-image-gallery 

I am trying to do with this method (Answer No.1) but I don't know how to add different image in loop

Comment: You should use horizontal RecyclerView and pass lambda as a click listener

Comment: @SFAH okay I'm implementing one for you with multiple images & posting as an answer in a short while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Then add this item to your `RecyclerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then call it from your Activity and set a `HORIZONTAL` LayoutManager to it and then its adapter:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        displayList()
    }

    private fun displayList() {
        val imageList = ArrayList<ImageDataModel>()
        imageList.clear()
        imageList.add(ImageDataModel("https://conversionxl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/coding-language.jpg", "Test"))
        imageList.add(ImageDataModel("https://makeawebsitehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/learn-code-e1455713167295.jpg", "Test"))
        imageList.add(ImageDataModel("https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Convert-PNG-to-JPG-Using-for-loop-Command.png", "Test"))
        imageList.add(ImageDataModel("https://conversionxl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/coding-language.jpg", "Test"))
        imageList.add(ImageDataModel("https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Convert-PNG-to-JPG-Using-for-loop-Command.png", "Test"))
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = ViewAdapter(imageList)
    }
}
```

As you can see the RecyclerView needs an Adapter too, it's a simple Adapter which uses [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to shown images like this:

```
class ViewAdapter(private val imageDataModelList: ArrayList<ImageDataModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(imageDataModelList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return imageDataModelList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindItems(imageDataModel: ImageDataModel) {
            val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)
            val imageView = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
            textView.text = imageDataModel.name

            Glide.with(itemView.context).load(imageDataModel.url).into(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add dependencies of Glide in your app-level `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
}
```

The app should look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpGuq.jpg

Comment: where you defined 'recylerView' ?

Comment: @SFAH inside `MainActivity` inside the method `displayList()`, since it's in Kotlin I don't need to initialize like in Java, this class can access id `recyclerView` of the layout `activity_main` directly.

Comment: Learn more about how I used Kotlin Extensions by importing Kotlin Synthetics in the following official documentation & example: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: One more question please , What is imageDataModelList? I can't used it ..

Comment: Sure, go on, no problem, I'm here to help. In the `MainActivity`, inside `displayList()`, I have a `val imageList = ArrayList<ImageDataModel>()`. Then I've passed this `ArrayList<ImageDataModel>()` to Adapter in this line: `recyclerView.adapter = ViewAdapter(imageList)`

Comment: And then in the ViewAdapter, I have `class ViewAdapter(private val imageDataModelList: ArrayList<ImageDataModel>)`, which means I've received that imageList as imageDataModelList here in the Adapter, I've just renamed while revceiving that's all.

Comment: Thankyou so much...BUt I cant understand this Datatype `ImageDataModel` What type of datatype this is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200354/discussion-between-saadaakash-and-sfah).

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically for RecyclerViews but there are some nice Kotlin language features you can use.

I personally would not do this with a constraint layout but a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView). Kotlin offers a couple of nice options for working with [collections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html) so its worth using those if you need to do any manipulation. I would advice you to not make the list available as mutable outside the adapter. This can be achieved with the use of [backing properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties).

As for making them clickable you could use an [OnItemTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html). However personally I prefer to use OnClickListener and a callback. The callback belongs to the adapter and the OnClickListener is added to the root view of the viewholder.

Besides this their are various nice tricks you can use like [typealias](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html).

Here is the code I could come up with quickly (I haven't done any non test app work with recyclerviews so don't have a properly worked out sample to draw on):

```
class ImageListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ImageListItemVH>() {
    private val _items = mutableListOf<ImageItem>()
    val items: List<ImageItem>
        get() = _items

    var clickCallback: ImageClickCallback? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImageListItemVH {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(
                R.layout.viewholder_image_list_item,
                parent,
                false
            )
        return ImageListItemVH(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = _items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageListItemVH, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(_items[position]) { clickCallback?.invoke(it) }
    }

    fun addItem(newItem: ImageItem) {
        _items += newItem
        notifyItemInserted(_items.size - 1)
    }

    fun addItems(newItems: List<ImageItem>) {
        val sizeBefore = _items.size
        _items += newItems
        notifyItemRangeInserted(sizeBefore - 1, newItems.size)
    }

    fun clearItems() {
        val sizeBefore = _items.size
        _items.clear()
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, sizeBefore - 1)
    }

    fun setItems(items: List<ImageItem>) {
        _items.clear()
        _items += items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ImageListItemVH(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(imageItem: ImageItem, callback: (id: String) -> Unit) =
            itemView.setOnClickListener { callback(imageItem.id) }
    }
}

data class ImageItem(
    val id: String,
    val location: String
)

typealias ImageClickCallback = (id: String) -> Unit
```

If the image collection is either of a large size or not limited to a small amount of static items you should use the [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/), specifically in this case the [PagedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList)